# Simple application built with laravel?

Tags: open-source, laravel, php

I am looking at getting into laravel, it looks like an awesome framework,but it seems to be missing one vital piece of it's documentation.. A "Getting started" tutorial.

A simple blog tutorial or similar or even an open source application built on laravel.
Does anyone have links to some good tutorials or resources for laravel?

I have come across [this nettuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/building-web-applications-from-scratch-with-laravel/), but it only skims over things very briefly. I was hoping there would be a tutorial that went more in depth.

There is of course the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs) but that again is more an overview of **what** you can use, it doesn't really tell you **how** to use them.

Comment: http://daylerees.com/category/laravel-tutorials/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try [daylerees.com/codebright](http://daylerees.com/codebright) (As mentioned by [@michel-sim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927581/simple-application-built-with-laravel#comment30496508_13927697))

It gives you a comprehensive tutorial from start to end and its well written

Also if you get stuck

The community is really helpful too. Check the [Forums](http://forums.laravel.com/)

**UPDATE**

Also I would recommend fallendown2005's laravel videos on YouTube. It really helps if you're a beginner

http://www.youtube.com/user/fallendown2005?feature=watch

Comment: It's now at http://daylerees.com/codebright

Comment: Link don't point on helpful resources anymore, but on a book  description about learning resources for the Laravel framework.

Answer (score 22):

I'm Nikko Bautista, the author of the Nettuts+ tutorials. I actually halted the writing the series since I thought Laravel 4 was due soon. I learned that it will come out next year though, so I will actually finish the other parts of the series as well.

Anyway, if you're looking for an application that's built using Laravel, you can check out this open source application I built as part of a hackaton back in the Philippines. It's called "Bukas Palad" (which means "Open Palms" in Tagalog). It's a donation and resources management system designed to help donation and relief centers keep track of donations and resources (this hackaton occurred during in the wake of one of the big storms in the Philippines in 2012).

You can find the code here:
http://webpilipinas.github.com/bukaspalad/

This actually makes use of a lot of Laravel components:

- Migrations
- Eloquent ORM
- Fluent Query Builder
- Events
- Routing
- View Composers
- Asset Management
- REST-based controllers
- Sessions
- Validation
- Inputs

If you have any questions, feel free to create issues on the GitHub page or ask here :)

Comment: Did you ever release the series for Laravel 4?

Comment: I have not - there simply is too much material out there right now. You should check out Jeffrey Way's series on Tuts+ - AFAIK it's free and very informative!

Answer (score 1):

Another simple one I have found: https://github.com/bstrahija/l4-site-tutorial

The updated fork is here: https://github.com/djodjoni/Laravel4_Example
and working version can be seen here: http://l4.djodjo.org

Answer (score 0):

I have created a few of these comprehensive tutorials back in Laravel 3 times and packaged them into a Udemy course. I made the course free of charge a couple months ago. These tutorials are still largely applicable to Laravel 4 for exception of very few syntax changes, perhaps while you will follow these you'll be able to figure out the changes from the docs:

http://udemy.com/develop-web-apps-with-laravel-php-framework/

Check them out and let me know if you need more, I post Laravel tutorials on my blog all the time.